# Where/Hos to access shared folder content in an oracleVM Ubuntu guest from windows 10 host

Tags: virtualbox, oracle, shared-folders

I'm trying to access a folder from my oracle VM running ubuntu as a guest and windows 10 as a host so I've already done the share folder thing in setting before launching the VM but I don't know what is it's directory and how to access it to perform a simple terminal command on a single file from the host computer.

Any guess as to how to do that?

Comment: My best advice is to install Vagrant on your host node. Vagrant will spin up your guest node and automatically configure a shared folder.  host node: CWD = guest node: /vagrant. VirtualBox and Vagrant are such great tools!

Comment: What is that Vagrant suppose to be? does it come to replace the VM or work with it? also I didn't get the host node part.

Comment: Vagrant will configure your guest in code. No more clicking around in Virtualbox Manager to add devices,disks, shared folders, network settings etc.. over and over again. Everything is described in a Vagrantfile. Run "vagrant up" and your guest will automatically be configured in a repeatable manner - the devops way. VirtualBox has an API "VBoxManage" which Vagrant integrates with. host node : current working directory will be your shared folder accessed from guest /vagrant  . Tip: search for "Vagrantfile" on github.com. There you will find amazing things!

Comment: 1. install guest additions
2. define shared folder(2).  These have a <name> and an auto-mount option
3. these are mounted to `/media/sf_<name>`
4. if these are not auto-mounted on reboot,  mount them `sudo mount -t vboxsf <name> /media/sf_<name>`   I have these mounts in a bash script that is called from crontab @reboot